# how to count each image a person has scrolled through

Tags: ios, swift, function

I currently have a UIScrollview named mainScrollView. I have an array of images called imageArray that has 8 images stored in it. I would like to create a way to count what image the user has scrolled onto in the scrollview. I have created the scrollviewdidscroll function and was wondering how I could count what image the user is on at the moment. I do have some code for you that is pretty basic.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
```

viewdidload():

```
mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1134.jpg"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1415.jpg"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1682.jpg"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0814.JPG"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1807.jpg"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1529.PNG"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1652.JPG"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1721.PNG"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_1818.PNG")]
    for i in 0..<imageArray.count  {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: mainScrollView.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}

}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
//count an int number of what image the user is currently on

}
```

I hope this helps and any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know the width and X position of each individual image, and it seems that the images are side by side with no space in between, so within the scrollViewDidScroll, if you just check the x position of the content offset, you can use simple math to figure out what image the user is currently on. So:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //find the content offset
    //then divide the content offset by the image width to figure out
    // what image the user is currently on(ish)
    scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width = ?
    //the '?' will be a decimal number, and you could round down or up
    //to figure out what image is currently being presented
}
```

EDIT: I personally would round down, to be safe! test it out and let me know if it works!

Comment: this did work just bummed I am having trouble with something else. Trying to count which image they are on to remove the last image they were on with a for loop Jay , if you would like take a look just ask bc that would be cool if you could take a look

Comment: So each time a user scrolls and passes an image, the moment it's off screen, you would like to remove the image from the UIScrollView? If so, I would highly recommend taking the approach Eric townsend mentioned, he is 100% right in that all of your problems would be easily solvable using a UITableView.

Comment: actually @user7424546 a UICollectionView would probably work better, due to the easily implementable horizontal scrolling capabilities! I can help out with that if you need.

Comment: every person i have ran into when asking this question says to use a collection view, but from what I know you cannot create a collection view to look the same as a scrollview like this : http://imgur.com/a/VWB8V. so this it false that I can make a collection view scroll horozontially and fill the whole screen like this scrollview? Thats why I am trying to work with a scrollview. @Jay

Comment: @user7424546 why can you not create a UICollectionView to look like that? What is preventing you?  In the storyboard, you add a UICollectionView to a UIViewController, set the constraints to the view, all set to 0, set the UICollectionView to Horizontal and then set the UICollectionView Cell height to match the bounds of the UIView.

Comment: I think the reason is due to the fact that it has less out of the box features, compared with a UICollectionView or UITableView. PS: For setting the CollectionView Size, do that in code, not within a storyboard!

Comment: jay @jay how can i round a number down, bc i just got what you meant when i just printed it. i have it set var x = scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width please help thanks Jay

Comment: @user7424546 floor(x)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are willing to change your logic, but it would be more simple to create a table view with each image as a cell, so you can just monitor what table cells are currently visible on the screen

Alternatively, using the same method you can add the indexPath to an array when ever a cell appears on the screen and just use the .last property of an array to know what's the last image they've seen.